# Why is this happening? (javaScript's reverse method)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

repl.it : https://repl.it/BuXR/3

```
var str = "abc";
var str2 = str.split(" ").join("").split("");
var tmp = str2;
console.log(str2);
// => ['a','b','c']
console.log(tmp.reverse());
// => ['c','b','a']
console.log(str2);
// => ['c','b','a']
```

My question is why str2 is being changed even though it is not being reversed?

This is very upsetting to me, but I have a guess as to why this is happening. The tmp is just a pointer to the original str2, and when I call reverse() on tmp, it actually reverses str2.

Even if that really is what's happening, I still feel like it is a very counterintuitive way for a language to work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript)

Comment: It's not a pointer to `str2`, but a pointer to the same array that `str2` points to.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you for the link.

Comment: @NickSpriet `string` is *not* a reference type in JavaScript. `str2` is an *Array*, not a string. It's not a very good name for that variable.

Comment: @JohnChen if this is counterintuitive to you, I recommend a language like MATLAB where pretty much everything is call-by-value.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Strings are exotic objects (like arrays), and are thus reference types. [See here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string-exotic-objects).

Comment: @DanPantry I see no indication in that documentation to suggest that exotic objects are "reference types".

Comment: @PatrickRoberts in JavaScript, exotic objects are a type of object. All objects constructed by a constructor are reference types - this includes all types that are not primitive. You can see this [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue), where `GetValue` will return `V` early if the type of the inspected object is not a reference (i.e primitive).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your guess is right.

The tmp is just a pointer to the original str2, so whatever operations are performed on str2 it will be stored to memory and when you access tmp it find the reference to str2.

> I have a guess as to why this is happening. The tmp is just a pointer
>   to the original str2, and when I call reverse() on tmp, it actually
>   reverses str2.

Comment: "disc space" refers to the memory on the disc where the array is stored. Just think of a "disc" as a flat cloud that can you can hold in your hands.

Comment: @user9993 I have changed the word Disc space to memory :)

Answer (score 11):

2 Reasons why this is happening:

- The `reverse()` method reverses an array **in place**, hence `tmp` is reversed: [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)
- The variable `tmp` and `str2` are references to the same array instance, hence `str2` also reversed.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is why str2 is being changed even though it is not being
>   reversed?

Since the `str2` and `tmp` are references which points to the same array. So whatever operation is done on `tmp` will be performed on string to which `str2` is also pointing to.

If you want it to point it to another array then simply try

```
var tmp = [].concat(str2);
```

Comment: `str2` isn't actually a string.

Comment: @Bergi thanks for correction, I spotted the same after typing :)

Comment: What is faster, `[].concat(arr)` or `arr.slice(0)`?

Comment: @GustavoRodrigues looks about the same https://jsperf.com/duplicate-array-slice-vs-concat/29

Comment: In ES6 you can now use `[...str2]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new point on memory of the array:

```
Array.prototype.clone = function(){
    return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this));
};
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var arr_clone = arr.clone();
arr_clone.reverse();
console.log(arr_clone);
// [3,2,1]
console.log(arr);
// [1,2,3]
```